# WordPress: How to retrieve custom field data from the page?

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to retrieve the value from a Custom field as below. It doesn't seem to get any value. Please point out the mistakes in it.

```
<?php 
$gift_text_lines = get_sub_field( 'gift_text_lines' ); 
if ($gift_text_lines > 1) { ?>
    .fluentform .ff-el-image-holder {
        min-height: 264px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
<?php 
} 
?>
```

Custom fields are as seen in the image below.

[image]

Comment: try `get_field( 'gift_text_lines' )` instead of `get_sub_field( 'gift_text_lines' )`

Comment: Can I also use get_field( 'hide_footer_signup_form' ) to find out if a checkbox is selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try get_field if get_sub_field not work for you.

```
if(in_array('hide_footer_signup_for', get_sub_field('gift_text_lines'))) 
{
        echo 'some html';
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this work? `$hide_footer_signup_form = get_field( 'hide_footer_signup_form' ); 
if (isset($hide_footer_signup_form)) { ?>
  #footer-form {
      display: none;
  }
<?php 
} `

Answer (score 1):

You can try out :

```
$gift_text_lines = get_field( 'gift_text_lines' );
```

Comment: Neal, thanks, could you please let me know how to check if checkbox custom field is selected? If selected, how to retrieve its value. The custom checkbox name is `hide_footer_signup_form`